# Qt5: QSqlDatabase::close()

Tags: c++, qt5, qsqldatabase

Как правильно закрыть за собой соединение с базой данных?

```
    void DestroyConnection()
    {
        QSqlDatabase::close();

    }
```

Данный код компилятор считает ошибочным и ругается так:

.`../dialog.h:83: ошибка: call to non-static member function without an object argument`

Comment: Обратиться к объекту экземпляра, и вызвать метод у него.

Comment: Если быть точным, то получается, что допустим у нас есть объект `Dialog *ldlg = new Dialog();` Там у нас есть некоторая база данных `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase();` Дальше чтобы её закрыть я должен обратиться к ней как? Заранее прошу прощения уже за откровенно глупые вопросы, но я уже чувствую баттхёрт от того, что в гугле мало вразумительной информации с понятным примером...

Comment: Вы игнорируете то что возвращает данный метод? [`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что вы создаёте соединение с БД через вызов статической член-функции addDatabase, которая в свою очередь возвращяем конкретный объект:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(...);
```

Следоветельно чтобы закрыть соединение необходимо вызвать:

```
db.close();
```

Также есть статическая функция [QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase), удобная для удаления соединения по-умолчанию (когда вы не указали явно имя соединения).

Comment: Пока что получилось что-то такое:
Сам объект лежит в классе как переменная-член, а дальше я его передаю в метод инициализации подключения, а закрываю базу так как вы сказали, но из метода. Пока не тестировал, как оно, у нас БД шлёпнулась. В случае чего в комментариях допишу о результатах